# CHECK_NRPE Could not connect to....: Connect reset by peer in Nagios NRPE

Tags: nagios, nrpe

Im working on opensuse Leap 42.1. I have installed NRPE on the remote host. I following precisely the installation guide. However, the deaemon runs:

```
netstat -at | egrep "nrpe|5666"
tcp        0      0 *:nrpe                  *:*                     LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:nrpe                  *:*                     LISTEN
```

But executing CHECK_NRPE gives me the following error:

```
/usr/local/nagios/lib/check_nrpe -H localhost
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not connect to ::e298:8aF0:2cdf:0: Connection reset by peer
```

I dont see what is the problem here. I tried the installation several times. Firewall is off, but that shouldn't be the problem. Haven't found the error anywhere else. What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Does it work with the IP address of the localhost (127.0.0.1)?  Do you have an entry in your /etc/hosts file for 'localhost'?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It works with 127.0.0.1 and I also have an entry for localhost `127.0.0.1       localhost`

Comment: You might want to disable IPv6 support, unless your entire network really supports it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Just, look the file: /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe

Now, find (almost at beggining) the line that says

> "disable = yes"

and simply change it to "no", then:

```
# systemctl restart xinetd.service
```

`# systemctl restart nrpe` or `# service nrpe restart` (if not systemd)

Testing on debian 8 with last nrpe installation guide.

Hope it helps!

PS: Don't forget the directive.

> "only_from = (...)"

**EDIT:**

In the last NRPE installation on debian 8 you have to:

Edit: /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg

line 98: `allowed_hosts=x.x.x.x`

And in the /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe let the directive "`disable`" in "`yes`". (default)

It seems like nrpe service look at allowed hosts in /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg instead of /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe.

Because in the /etc/xinetd.d/nrpe there is this line:

```
 server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
```

Now, yes:

```
# systemctl restart nrpe.service && systemctl restart xinetd.service
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that

Comment: "disable = yes" and "only_from = (...)" were the culprits, thanks !

Comment: In my case (using xinetd), the issue was `only_from = 127.0.0.1` -- when I changed to `only_from = localhost` all was well.

Answer (score 2):

in my case the issue was only i need to stop nrpe process and start again

```
ps aux | grep nrpe

kill xxxx


run nrpe service

/usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg -d
```